# django KeyError for my i18n javascript catalog url

Tags: django, django-i18n

This is a bit odd. I'm using Django 1.9.6, and it doesn't like my i18n `javascript_catalog` url after I changed it from the obsolete 1.7 syntax (I finally decided I should do something about that "not gonna work in django 1.10" warning I get every time I `runsrever`). Here's what I've got:

urls.py

```
from django.views.i18n import javascript_catalog

js_info_dict = {
    'domain': 'djangojs',
    'packages': ('my_app',),
}

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^jsi18n/(?P<packages>\S+?)/$', 
        javascript_catalog, js_info_dict, name='javascript_catalog'),

]
```

When trying to render:

```
KeyError at /my_app/my_url/
'packages'
```

I can't remove the `'packages'` key from `django_info_dict`, because it causes `NoReverseMatch` error: `Reverse for 'javascript_catalog' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.`

As you'd expect, here's where it occurs in the template.html:

```
<script src="{% url 'javascript_catalog' %}"></script>
```

This is pretty much copy-paste from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#module-django.views.i18n). I've got the django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog view and the name in the url ... what am I overlooking here?

Comment: What are you trying to match with `packages`?

Comment: my application - there's just one in this urls.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought the `'packages'` key referred to the one in the js_info_dict. In the error it actually referred to the capturing regex group named `packages`. The dynamic `packages` variable was not needed because I specified a static package `my_app` in the `js_info_dict`, hence the correct url pattern to use was:

```
url(r'^jsi18n/$', javascript_catalog, js_info_dict, name='javascript_catalog'),
```